# Set pre-defined value for filter in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to set a user-defined search value in a filter on a kendo grid. As soon as the user opens the filter, the value will be placed into the search box. Any advice would be much appreciated.

This is similar question to [Set default filter for Kendo UI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321414/set-default-filter-for-kendo-ui-grid) except that I'm using angular js and I want a user-defined string filter value:

[image: A kendo grid with a pre-defined string value entered into the filter]

This is how I build my grid. I'm using angular js to create a div with custom attributes. The most notable attributes are `sg-grid` (the kendo grid itself), `sg-filterable` (set to true to indicate that this grid should be filterable) and `sg-predefine-filter` (also set to true to indicate that this grid's filter should have a string entered into the search box when it opens):

1. Markup

   ```
   <div sg-grid sg-data="api/grid/accounts"
    sg-columns="accountId,name,pricingFrequency,shortName,status"
    sg-filterable="true"
    sg-predefine-filter-value="true"                     
   </div>
   ```
2. Scripting (simplified to demo here)

   ```
   angular.module('sgComponents').directive('sgGrid', [         
      return {
         restrict: 'AE',
         scope: { filterable: @sgFilterable, predefineFilterValue: @sgPredefineFilterValue},
         template: '<div class="sg-grid">\
                       <div class="pager-bar">\
                          <div></div>\ // THE KENDO GRID
                       </div>\                                
                    </div>',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            buildGrid();
            function buildGrid() {
               var grid = element.find(':nth-child(2)'); // 2nd DIV IN THE TEMPLATE
               var gridOptions = buildGridOptions(scope, attrs, grid);
               grid.kendoGrid(gridOptions); // build the grid
             };
             /**
              Builds the options for the grid
             */
             function buildGridOptions(scope, attrs, grid) {
                if (scope.filterable === 'true') {
                   opts.filterable = {};
                   opts.filterable.operators = {};
                   opts.filterable.operators.string = {}
                   if (scope.predefineFilterValue === 'true') { // set a pre-defined value if true
                      opts.filterable.operators.string = {
                         eq: 'Is equal to', value:'Test'
                      }
                   } else { // just show the filter option
                      opts.filterable.operators.string = {
                         eq: 'Is equal to'
                      }
                   }                                                 
                }
             }

          }   
      };                   
   ]);
   ```
3. Here is an image of the console log:

[image: A screenshot of the console showing the JSON gridOptions object that I pass to the kendoGrid]

The outcome. As you can see, my value is added as another filter option. I don't want this, I want it to be in the input box as a value!

[image: A screenshot of the grid showing the filter with the value 'Test' in the wrong place.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found a [kendo forum question](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/data-source/custom-filtering.aspx) that set me in the right direction!

The solution is not to add the pre-set filter value while constructing the grid but to do it once the grid has finished building using the kendoGrid.dataSource.filter object:

```
angular.module('sgComponents').directive('sgGrid', [         
   return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: { filterable: @sgFilterable, predefineFilterValue: @sgPredefineFilterValue},
      template: '<div class="sg-grid">\
                <div class="pager-bar">\
                   <div></div>\ // THE KENDO GRID
                </div>\                                
             </div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         buildGrid();
         function buildGrid() {
            //code same as in original question
            grid.kendoGrid(gridOptions); // build the grid
         };
         /*
          * Builds the options for the grid
          */
         function buildGridOptions(scope, attrs, grid) {             
            //code same as in original question
         }

         /*
          * the grid has finished building so 
          * now get hold of it and pre-set the 
          * filter value.
          * The values (the field to filter, the type of filter and the value) 
          * are hard-coded here but ultimately would 
          * come from a JSON object on the scope, constructed
          * using values from the model
         */
         kendoGrid = gridElem.data('kendoGrid'); // the grid

         //If the attribute to pre-set a filter value is true...             
         if (scope.predefineFilterValue === 'true') {             
            var ds = kendoGrid.dataSource; // the datasource object has a filter object
            ds.filter([
            {
               "logic":"or", // could be 'and'
               "filters":[{
                  "field":"accountId", // the column you want to filter
                  "operator":"eq", // the type of filter
                  "value":105 // the value, hard-coded for testing
               }]
            }
         }
      }
   }                           
]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should specify the `filter` option on the datasource of the grid.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    filter : [{
        field: "name", operator: "eq", value: "John Doe"
    }]
});
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Just a comment: I think those `[]` in `filter` are not necessary. At least they are not in the documentation (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.field).