# How to customize Kendo date filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to customize Kendo filter for grid view. for this purpose, I am using below code.

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .StartsWith("Starts with")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
        )
        .ForDate(dt => dt.Clear()
        .IsGreaterThan("Is greater than")
        .IsLessThan("Is less than")
        .IsEqualTo("Is Equal to")
        ))
    )
```

This code works perfectly. But in date filter only one text box is displaying. I want to select data between two dates.

How can I achieve this in Kendo grid date filter?

Comment: Create two fields? Start and end?

Comment: In kendo, there is no any option with Start and End.Can you share any code?

Comment: With fields, I mean not properties/methods. Why not creating two different datetime pickers?

Comment: I tried this             .ForDate(dt => dt.Clear()
            .IsGreaterThan("Is greater than")
            .IsLessThan("Is less than")
            .IsEqualTo("Is Equal to")
            )
            .ForDate(dt => dt.Clear()
            .IsLessThanOrEqualTo("Is Less Than Or Equal To")
            ))

Comment: You seem to be confused between filter and input elements. A filter filters the selection range of a specific input element. Since you want to define a timespan, in range from a start and a end date, you need two different `DateTime` input elements. Not two different filters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a Kendo grid Column filter between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060935/how-to-define-a-kendo-grid-column-filter-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Below solution works for me.

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .StartsWith("Starts with")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to"))

        .ForDate(dt => dt.Clear()
        .IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Begin Date")
        .IsLessThanOrEqualTo("End Date")))
        .Extra(true).Messages(mes => mes.Info("Show items between dates")))
```