# Kendo Grid kendoDateRangePicker for kendo-grid-react-wrapper

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to introduce something like kendoDateRangePicker for kendo-grid-react-wrapper. There is kendoDatePicker that allows you to pick only one date but not two:

```
filterable : {
 cell: {
   template: function (args) {
       args.element.kendoDatePicker({
       });
   },
   showOperators: true,
   enabled: true                        
 },         
}
```

I'm solving similar issue [How to define a Kendo grid Column filter between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060935/how-to-define-a-kendo-grid-column-filter-between-two-dates) but for kendo-grid-react-wrapper.
The task involves configuration that '@progress/kendo-grid-react-wrapper' doesn't have, namely filterCell in GridColumn from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
Using kendo-react components it can be easily achieved by https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/filtering/
but there is no filterCell property in the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

This can done with wrapper and the template function:

1) Column :

```
        <GridColumn field="OrderDate" title="Order Date" format="{0: yyyy-MM-dd}" filterable={this.filterableDates} />
```

2) Filterable:

```
    this.filterableDates = {
  cell: {
    template: function (args) {
      let valueOne = null;
      let valueTwo = null;
      let grid = $('.k-grid').data('kendoGrid')
      let parent = $(args.element).parent()
      $(parent).append("<input id='second'>")
      args.element.kendoDatePicker({
        change: function (e) {
          valueOne = e.sender.value()
          grid.dataSource.filter({
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
              { field: "OrderDate", operator: "ge", value: valueOne },
              { field: "OrderDate", operator: "le", value: valueTwo }
            ]
          })
        }
      });
      $("#second").kendoDatePicker({
        change: function (e) {
          valueTwo = e.sender.value()
          grid.dataSource.filter({
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
              { field: "OrderDate", operator: "ge", value: valueOne },
              { field: "OrderDate", operator: "le", value: valueTwo }
            ]
          })
        }
      });
    },
    showOperators: true,
    enabled: true
  },
}
```

This will filter the Grid when the value of the pickers is changed.

This is [full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zlhvga?file=app/main.js)