# Kendo Pivot Grid doesn't work with operator gte

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, pivot, operator-keyword

I have create a kendo pivot [grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid/index) like the example. I have this options

```
                $scope.options = {
                "dataSource": {
                    "type": "xmla",
                    "columns": [],
                    "rows": [{
                        "name": ["[Date].[Hierarchy - QM]"],
                        "expand": false
                    }],
                    "measures": [],
                    "transport": {
                        "connection": {
                            "catalog": "EDI",
                            "cube": "EDI"
                        },
                        "read": {
                            "url": "..../msmdpump.dll",
                            "type": "POST",
                            "dataType": "text",
                            "contentType": "text/xml"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "field": "[Date].[Hierarchy - QM]",
                        "operator": "eq",
                        "value": "new Date(2016, 1, 1)"
                    },
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "xmla"
                    }
                }
            }
```

and all works perfect. **BUT, when i change the filter operator from 'eq' to 'gte'** i get the following error

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321414/set-default-filter-for-kendo-ui-grid